# Java how to secure http connection query string URL request passing & getting sensitive data?

Tags: java, ssl, https, httprequest, query-string

The following plain java code is calling some web service API:

```
String url = "https://my_web_service/some_function?password=my_password";
InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
String result = readAll(rd);  //result is also sensitive data!
```

Does it's a safe way to transmit & get sensitive data? Assuming arguments like this not relevant:

> "SSL is secure, but remember that any encryption can be broken if given enough time..."

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, it is safe since query parameters are encrypted by SSL certificate's key. Use google search next time, your question isn't anything unique.

Comment: @Andremoniy Yes it's **encrypted**. No it's not safe. It's explained it the duplicate you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are using modern ciphers, you can consider SSL secure.
It is still vulnerable to [man-in-the-middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks though - [certificate pinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Certificate_pinning) and [other practices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack#Defences_against_the_attack) are designed to prevent these attacks.

Another issue in your is that you are passing password as a query parameter - it's better to pass it in the request body. Otherwise it will be printed in the server access logs and client logs (probably).

If it was a web page, not the web service it will also be stored in browser history, bookmarks, e.t.c.

Comment: Ok, so I'll move request params to body. But what about the response? Is "By definition" it's OK in above case? Thanks,

Comment: @michael yes, response body is ok.

Comment: @bedrin "passwords in urls are a bad idea", one more reason: securityweek.com/hackers-can-intercept-https-urls-proxy-atta‌​cks